# Low-level caching in Rails 5

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-5

Since upgrading to Rails 5, I'm unable to perform low-level caching in my application. Hence, I'm unable to test my code (background jobs in particular). As suggested, my `development.rb` file contains-

```
if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {'Cache-Control' =>'public, max-age=172800'}
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```

And, as suggested, i have run `rails dev:cache`. As I mentioned, my `views` call some low-level cached method results. These are not being cached even after the `view` is served. However, when I call the low-level method from console, a second time, it is being cached. Further, I have a background job to call the same low-level method on some associated records. These are not being cached either, though my sidkiq worker job runs.
 The problem is only with the low-level cache, and the `view-fragments` are being cached just fine. Can someone identify the problem, please?

P.S. I have checked, and the file`tmp/caching-dev.txt` exists.